# Are unpaid utilities of the previous tenant required to be paid before service can be started?

Tags: california, utility-bills

Company in question: LADWP

Area: Los Angeles/CA

Our last roommate refused to pay his share of the electricity bill during a lengthy eviction process by our landlord. The account is only in his name, and he turned the electricity service off. We were looking to get service restored, but when we called we were told even once we sign a new lease with a new roommate, they require the bill to be paid off before they will resume service. I want to know if this is legal, and if it is, are there any things that can be done to avoid paying this debt to resume service, or if there isn't, is the only course of action to pay his debt and then take him to small claims court.

Comment: Isn't this your own debt to the utility company? That is, your title asks about "previous tenant" but the body seems to state that *you* are the previous tenant.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase that @BryanKrause. I am one of the 3 tenants that was living in the unit at the time. One of the tenants was evicted, and the entire electric account was under his name, while all 3 of our names were on the lease. Me and my other roommate have been logging into the account and paying our share.

Comment: Does your contract with the utility expect you to each pay only your share? While that may be your arrangement with your former roommate, I'd expect your contract with the utility says you are all responsible for the whole bill.

Comment: @BryanKrause Our names were never on the utility bill, we never signed or agreed to any contract with the utility company, so I don't see how we could be responsible for the bill at all. This roommate had electric service set up before we moved in, and we simply logged into the account using our former roommates credentials and paid a third of the amount every time a bill came in.

Comment: On the other hand, the utility company lost money on a home where the two of you lived. They won't like that. Should they be forced to restore service? And then, if you leave because it is too cold and three unrelated persons move in, what then?

Comment: @gnasher729 Whomever signed up for the utility is responsible for the utility. The utility company has to change its billing invoice to reflect a new tenant and new service under a new name.

Comment: @gnasher729 when I contacted the utility company, their response was that as long as someone of the original group of tenants is still living in the unit, they will not restore power while the debt is unpaid. If an entirely new set of tenants move in they will restore power without forcing them to pay the debt. I don't believe that is legal because my name was not on the account for the power, however I can't afford a lawyer to pursue it, so I'm asking if anyone knows what I can do as a tenant.

Comment: @paulj if the utility company changes its billing invoice to reflect his eviction, can they then legally force us the assume the debt on the account?

Comment: @user47252 - They could, from my layman knowledge, not legal.1-800-649-7570 for assistance if your utility service is in jeopardy of being disconnected. CPUC website https://oag.ca.gov/consumers/general/utilities